# Angular - correct way of subscribing inside a for loop

Tags: angular, for-loop, subscribe

Below is my code

```
    if(rTC) {
        for(let i=0; i<rTC.length; i++) {
            let getTID = rTC.controls[i].get['triggerTypeId'].value;
            this.baseService.getCFTType(getTID, this.baseService.productId).subscribe(val => {
                const cMFID = savedData.repReg.repT[i].cMFID;
                rTC.controls[i].get('cMFID').setValue(cMFID);
            });
        }
    }
```

Here, I am trying to loop through my `formgroups` and set the values of a `dropdown` in each row with the results coming from a subscription.

But, what is happening here is, only the dropdown value of last row is getting set. I am assuming that something is wrong with how the usage of `subscribe` inside `for` loop. Can somebody please help me with this? Thanks

Comment: did you try to set "i" as parameter in getCFTType function? Something like `this.baseService.getCFTType(getTID, this.baseService.productId, i).subscribe({value, i} => {...})`. I assume that i iterates up to the last number and this number is used in the callback of all subscriptions because it's asynchronous.

Comment: On its own, this code doesn't do anything. Please provide a reproducible example. You will most likely find your problem while trying to reproduce it. There's nothing wrong with subscribing in a for loop, if you do `console.log(i)` in the subscription, you will see each subscription gets its own `i` value.